# Como dividir uma string em PHP?

Tags: php

Preciso pegar dois itens no magnet link

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021&dn=Splinter.Cell.Blacklist-RELOADED&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337
```

o valor depois de btih:, que é :

```
0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021
```

e os valores de tr:

```
udp://tracker.com:80
```

***como faço isso ?***

Comment: vc precisa de todos os valores depois de `tr=` ou somente primeiro?

Comment: todos os valores, preciso somar eles...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outra abordagem é utilizar uma regex para a string após `btih:` e utilizar `explode()` para pegar todos os seeds(`udp://tracker.com:80`)

```
preg_match('/(?:btih:)+([a-z0-9]+)(?:&dn=)/i', $link, $torrent);
$seeds =  explode('&tr=', $link);

echo 'o torrent: '. $torrent[1] . ' possui os seguintes seeds : <br>';
array_splice($seeds, 0, 1); //remove o primeiro elemento do array

foreach ($seeds as $item){
    echo urldecode($item).'<br>';
}
```

Isso elimina, a sujeira retornada de explode que é:`magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0eb69459a28b0840 ...continua` pois o ponto de *corte* é `&tr=` ou seja o que estiver a direita também vai para o array.

```
 array_splice($seeds, 0, 1);
```

A saida do código:

```
o torrent: 0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021 possui os seguintes seeds :
udp://tracker.com:80
udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80
udp://tracker.istole.it:6969
udp://tracker.ccc.de:80
udp://open.demonii.com:1337
```

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas um jeito seria usar uma expressão regular:

```
^.*?btih\:([^&]+).*?tr\=([^&]+).*$
```

Detalhando:

- `^` - início da string
- `.*?` - seguido de qualquer coisa (avaliação preguiçosa)
- `btih\:` - seguido da string `btih:`
- `([^&]+)` - seguido de qualquer coisa que não for um `&` (primeiro grupo de captura)
- `.*?` - seguido de qualquer coisa (avaliação preguiçosa)
- `tr\=` - seguido da string `tr=`
- `([^&]+)` - seguido de qualquer coisa que não for um `&` (segundo grupo de captura)
- `.*` - seguido de qualquer coisa (avaliação gulosa)
- `$` - fim da string

Código completo:

```
$string = "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0eb69459a28b08400c5f05bad3e63235b9853021&dn=Splinter.Cell.Blacklist-RELOADED&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337";
$regex = "/^.*?btih\:([^&]+).*?tr\=([^&]+).*$/";
if ( preg_match($regex, $string, $resultados) ) {
    /* $resultados[1] é o valor depois de btih: */
    /* $resultados[2] é o valor do orimeiro tr= */
}
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/6glbWT).